# "non-finite function value" error when integrating in R

Tags: r

I am trying to integrate following function from -Inf to Inf:

```
int <- function(x) {x*exp(0.5*x)*(1-exp(-0.5*exp(0.5*x)*2))*dnorm(x)}
integrate(int,lower=-Inf,upper=Inf)
```

I got the error "non-finite function value". I couldn't solve this error. Does anyone know how to solve it? Many thanks!

Comment: Means the function diverges. You cannot integrate. Eg integrate e^x from 0 to Infinity will give the same error. The area under your curve is infinity

Comment: @onyambu I plot it with `curve(int, -10, 10)` and it looks convergent. I try different pairs of `lower` and `upper`, and some succeed. I still can't figure out why the OP's code fails.

Comment: Even when you plot exp(x) from -10 to 10 might seem convergent. What value does your function give at infinity?

Comment: Ie what is the result of `int(1e7)`

Comment: Also when you say the first *term* is `x^2` do you mean the factor? terms are separated by + and - while factors are separated by `*` and `/`

Comment: @onyambu yes, factor x^2. I have edited it.

Comment: Also note that you could simplify it abit, you have `exp(-0.5*exp(0.5*x)*2)` this is simply `exp(-exp(0.5*x))` Note that the 2 can multiply the 0.5

Comment: Check whether [this is correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E2*exp%280.5*x%29*%281-exp%28-0.5*exp%280.5*x%29*2%29%29*+exp%28-x%5E2%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29+from+-inf+to+inf)

Comment: @onyambu yes, you are right. In my own function, 0.5 and 2 are values of different parameters. I just use 0.5 and 2 in this case. So I did not multiply together. How can we know this function is divergent?

Comment: @XianwenZhang the function is convergent. Check the link I posted. The answer is given

Comment: @onyambu the first factor should be x not x^2

Comment: `int(100000)` returns
[1] NaN and `100000*exp(0.5*100000)` returns
[1] Inf` So you have Inf * 0 which is "not a number"

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the order of operations. In R the order of multiplication/division is done from left to right as per most systems. (JUST TO POINT OUT YOU CAN ALWAYS DO DIVISION FIRST BEFORE MULTIPLICATION, unless two divisions follow one another)

Now due to this rule, your function produces infinity  when x is large in the first part before you multiply by dnorm, hence giving `NaN` ie `Inf * 0`. In this case, we can use an ifelse statement to return 0 whenever the function produces `NaN`:

```
int <- function(x) {
  res <- x^2*exp(0.5*x)*(1-exp(-0.5*exp(0.5*x)*2))*dnorm(x)
  ifelse(is.nan(res),0,res)
  }
integrate(int,lower=-Inf,upper=Inf)

1.15656 with absolute error < 5.9e-05
```

On the other hand, you can just rearrange the order so that `dnorm` is computed first.

```
int <- function(x) dnorm(x)* x^2*exp(0.5*x)*(1-exp(-0.5*exp(0.5*x)*2))
integrate(int,lower=-Inf,upper=Inf)
1.15656 with absolute error < 5.9e-05
```

This is the result produced by [`wolfram Alpha`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E2*exp%280.5*x%29*%281-exp%28-0.5*exp%280.5*x%29*2%29%29*+exp%28-x%5E2%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29+from+-inf+to+inf)

Comment: @XianwenZhang I have it as x^2. The very first factor is `x^2* exp...`

Comment: @XianwenZhang in the first answer I gave, just remove the `^2` part. Surely that is something you can do. Surely the answer given plus the link is enough for you to solve the problem